# How do I extract value from for loop and group them uniformly

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to divide an entry from a for loop into equal parts. For example, I have a for loop which runs upto 100(this is not fixed in my actual code) and the first 4 values of the loop that is 1:4 is supposed to be saved in a cell/array and the next 4 values are saved in consecutive array and then I want to execute the result(cells). I tried a matlab code for it but I don't know why all the values are getting saved in the initial cell and the preceeding storage is ambigous.Please give me a solution. For example(I tried with a small number)

```
function a=groupit(n)
counter=1;
x=0;
for i=1:n
    x=x+i;
    if mod(i,3)==0
        counter=counter+1;
    end
    a{counter,1}=x;
end
end
```

When I call `groupit(10)`, I receive the following restls:

```
> 4×1 cell array
> 
>     {[ 3]}
>     {[15]}
>     {[36]}
>     {[55]}
```

Comment: your expected output? If it supposed to be a group of row vectors then you also need to change 2nd argument of `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a for-loop to get desired results. The following divides `n` values to groups of maximum size of `m`:

```
function a = groupit(n, m)
p = floor(n/m)*m; % largest number divisible by m and smaller than n
a = mat2cell(1:p, 1, m*ones(1, p/m))';
if p<n
    a = [a; (p+1):n];
end
end
```

Call it like:

```
X = groupit(10, 4)

clc
% displaying contents
disp('Contents:')
cellfun(@(x)disp(x), X, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The results:

> ```
> X = 
>
>     [1x4 double]
>     [1x4 double]
>     [1x2 double]
>   
> Contents:  
>      1     2     3     4  
>      5     6     7     8  
>      9    10
> ```